# WINDOWS CMD: Why do i recieve errors when typing php-v at the prompt?

Tags: php, cmd

Im on windows xp.  I receive errors at the prompt when i run the php-v command.  The first error i receive is:

The procedure entry point OCILobRead2 could not be located in the dynamic link library OCI.dll
and then after that a slew of .dll errors.

Fact is that all my .dll's are in D:Program Files\PHP\ext so im quite sure this is a problem with OCI.dll.  Also my extention dir in my php.ini file is D:Program Files\PHP\ext so i think im good there.  (Where is OCI.dll meant to reside??)

Anyone have any ideas as to what i need to do.  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are in for quite a ride, the steps are described over at [oracle.com forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2324855)

Apparently there are different solutions described there, so please let us know what worked for you.